# How can I configure innodb's innodb_autoinc_lock_mode with xampp/phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp, innodb

Hey guys Im currently testing my project on my local xampp server. I need to alter innodb_autoinc_lock_mode and I have no idea how to go about this. Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 3):

change it in xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini and restart the mysql service